# Find the gradient of the normal to the function: $f( x )= 5 \sin ( 3 x − 1 )$ at $x = 1$

Tags: calculus

> Find the gradient of the normal to the function:  $f( x )= 5 \sin ( 3 x − 1 )$ at $x = 1$.

Working on this question, I get the answer $-6.24$, but the real answer is $0.16$. I feel like I'm missing something, especially with the "Of the normal."

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you arrived at that answer which helps readers of your question detect any errors you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You found the slope of the tangent line.  The normal is perpendicular to the tangent line.

Comment: Since its a normal, let whatever you found be $m$, now find $-\dfrac1m$.